# C# - WCF - Web Service from IIS to Self Host

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, iis

I'm updating an application which connects to an access database, which lacks any security.

In the future, it will be on an IIS server with an SQL database, so I chose to create a web service to add an extra security layer. The application works fine with the web service and the .NET development server.

I'll have access to the server in a month, but the application needs to be released in a week, so I decided to make the application self-host the service, and use an access database until the server is ready.

Actually, i've got two projects in my solution: AppServer and AppClient (with web service reference to AppServer). When the application is running, I can access the service using a web browser.

How can I self-host my service easily so it won't be hard to switch the host to IIS when it's ready?

I've tried playing with ServiceHost but it didn't worked very well since it's a windows forms app and I experience lags and timeouts:

```
Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:53333/AppServer.svc");
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(AppServerClient), httpUrl);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAppServer), new WSHttpBinding(), "");

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

host.Open();
```

I found that code to run the service in a different thread: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16299/Hosting-WCF-services-in-a-Windows-Forms-Applicatio

I added this code to my application (the URL is the same as the service reference)

```
ThreadedServiceHost<AppServerClient, IAppServer> host = new ThreadedServiceHost<AppServerClient, IAppServer>("http://localhost:53333/AppServer.svc", "", new WSHttpBinding());
```

When I run my application, I get the message

```
Http://localhost:53333/AppServer.svc connection impossible. 
TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it 127.0.0.1:53333.
```

When I use my web browser, I get the following message: You have created a service. To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service.

I read a bit on the channel factory which seems a good choice when you self host the service from a to z, but since it will be hosted on another server soon, I want to avoid having to change every call to the service in the application.

I'd really appreciate any help to fix that problem.